# VBOs with std::vector

Tags: c++, opengl, vector, vbo

I've written a model loader in C++ an OpenGL. I've used `std::vector`s to store my vertex data, but now I want to pass it to `glBufferData()`, however the data types are wildly different. I want to know if there's a way to convert between `std::vector` to the documented `const GLvoid *` for `glBufferData()`.

#### Vertex type

```
typedef struct
{
    float x, y, z;
    float nx, ny, nz;
    float u, v;
}
Vertex;

vector<Vertex> vertices;
```

#### glBufferData() call

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * 3 * sizeof(float), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

I get the following (expected) error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘std::vector<Vertex>’ to ‘const GLvoid*’ in argument passing
```

How can I convert the vector to a type compatible with `glBufferData()`?

*NB. I don't care about correct memory allocation at the moment; `vertices.size() * 3 * sizeof(float)` will most likely segfault, but I want to solve the type error first.*

Comment: @john Edited \*cheesy, sheepish smile\*.

Comment: The main issue is whether your Vertex struct is laid out in the way that OpenGL expects. I have no idea about that, but assuming it is, then all I think you need to do is replace `vertices` with `&vectices[0]` in your call to glBuggerData.

Comment: @john I edited glBuggerData out! Anyway, I've made my `Vertex` struct in a very similar way to other examples I've seen, so I'm assuming OpenGL is happy with it.

Comment: @JamWaffles: Don't forget to fix that `3 * sizeof(float)` problem as Marcelo pointed out. You're not passing an array where each entry is 3 floats; you're passing an array where each entry is a `Vertex` object. That's much bigger than 3 floats.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you have a `std::vector<T> v`, you may obtain a `T*` pointing to the start of the contiguous data (which is what OpenGL is after) with the expression `&v[0]`.

---

In your case, this means passing a `Vertex*` to `glBufferData`:

```
glBufferData(
   GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
   vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex),
   &vertices[0],
   GL_STATIC_DRAW
);
```

Or like this, which is the same:

```
glBufferData(
   GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
   vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex),
   &vertices.front(),
   GL_STATIC_DRAW
);
```

---

You can rely on implicit conversion from `Vertex*` to `void const*` here; that should not pose a problem.

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation Tomalak. As @Marcelo has suggested, I'll be using `&vertices.front()`, unless there's a good reason I shouldn't be?

Comment: @JamWaffles: No reason at all.

Comment: This will work with vectors because vector data-storage is a C array under the hood. This will not work for many other STL containers (like lists sets and maps) where the data is not stored contiguously

Comment: @doron: Whether `vector` storage is implemented with arrays is completely unspecified. What is important is that the elements are guaranteed to be stored _contiguously_. This is pretty much the same thing, but there _is_ a subtle difference in meaning there. (FYI, _no_ other standard container guarantees contiguous element storage, besides `std::array` of coure)

Comment: Why `sizeof(std::vector<Vertex>::value_type)`, why not `sizeof(Vertex)`?

Comment: @Andreas: I think I started with `vertices::value_type`, realised my mistake, and expanded it rather than contracting it. :)

Comment: You can also use `vertices.data()` which returns a pointer directly. (&vertices[0] might actually fail more cleanly in the case of an accidentally empty vector though).

Comment: @user673679: How so? `&v[0]`, `v.data()` and `&v.front()` are all 100% equivalent. Well, except that `v.data()` in itself is well-defined when `v` is empty, whereas the other two are not.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well, I had an issue at one point where v.data() resulted in a crash, and &v[0] triggered an assertion about the index being out of range (IIRC), which made it easier to track down the bug. Entirely an implementation dependent thing though I guess.

Comment: @user673679: Yes it is - that would have been debug mode range checking which the standard does not require of `&v[0]` and which you should never see in a release build. Though if `v.data()` "resulted in a crash" then you have a horribly broken stdlib implementation; it should have only crashed once you'd dereferenced it! The standard makes it explicitly clear that `v.data()` is a valid (but potentially undereferenceable) pointer, much like "end" iterators.

Answer (score 33):

This should do the trick:

```
&vertices[0]
```

Some prefer `&vertices.front()`, but that's more typing and I'm bone lazy.

To be even lazier, you could overload `glBufferData` thus:

```
template <class T>
inline void glBufferData(GLenum target, const vector<T>& v, GLenum usage) {
    glBufferData(target, v.size() * sizeof(T), &v[0], usage);
}
```

Then you can write:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

and also avoid bugs (your struct is bigger than `3 * sizeof(float)`).

Comment: Thanks Marcelo. `&vertices.front()` is perfect. I was confused by the fact that you don't pass all the data to the function, only a pointer to the first element. All fixed.