# VBO of std::vector<MyClass*> and correct strides

Tags: c++, opengl, stl, vbo

I'm wondering how to get the maximum data locality and performance for the following problem **without** data copy.

I've a std::vector< MyClass* > where `MyClass` is something like

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(int n,double px,double py,double pz)
    {
        someField=n;
        x=px;
        y=py;
        z=pz;
        anotherField=100;
        anotherUnusefulField=-10.0;
    }

    int someField;
    int anotherField;


    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    double anotherUnusefulField;
};

std::vector<MyClass*> myClassVector;
// add some values and set x,y,z

for (std::vector<MyClass*>::iterator iter = myClassVector.begin(); iter!=myClassVector.end();++iter)
{
    MyClass *tmp = *iter;
    tmp->x+=1.0;
    tmp->y+=2.0;
    tmp->z+=3.0;
}
```

I'm iterating frequently on these data and I also would like to enforce data locality. The data contained in the pointer to MyClass should be sent to a OpenGL vertex array, where the vertices are **ONLY** determined by `x,y,z` variables. As you may imagine is difficult to correctly set the strides, so I'm here to ask if there are other (portable) solution to this problem.

(p.s. I've already read the post [VBOs with std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173494/vbos-with-stdvector) but my case is basically different because I have pointers and I also have other variables inside the class.)

Comment: which part of data copy? can you elaborate?

Comment: If `MyClass` only contains member variables like you illustrate, then storing them directly in a vector will make them the most friendly to data locality.  With the pointer approach you take here, I suspect you're thrashing the CPUs cache, let alone how useless the data are to OpenGL.

Answer (score 1):

> I have pointers

Those pointers are useless to OpenGL, as they're in client address space. Also OpenGL doesn't dereference second level pointers.

> and I also have other variables inside the class.

Well, then don't do this. If you passed those class instances to OpenGL you'd copy a lot of useless data. I recommend you just store a index into a tightly packed std::vector or array in your class members, and a reference to the vector/array itself. You can use getter/setter/referencer member functions to abstract away the access to the vector, i.e.

```
class …
{

    // …
    std::vector<v_t> *v;
    size_t index_v;
    x_t getX() const { return (*v)[index_v]; }
    x_t setX(x_t x) { return (*v)[index_v] = x;}
    x_t &x() { return (*v)[index_v]; }

};
```