# C++ - OpenGL - glBufferData with std::vector

Tags: c++, opengl, vector

I want to use the function glBufferData to fill up some indices/vertices.
But I have my arrays in a std::vector and the glBufferData only allows char*.

```
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(m_indicesEBO), m_indicesEBO, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

How can I use std::vector here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, seen [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173494/vbos-with-stdvector) is:

```
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(m_indicesEBO), &m_indicesEBO.front(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Using the pointer to the beginning of the vector with .front()

Comment: You missed the `* m_indicesEBO.size()` part...

Comment: You are right @Christian Hackl

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way, assuming `m_indicesEBO` is a std::vector.

```
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_indicesEBO.size() * sizeof(<data type>), &m_indicesEBO[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```